# How to convert my SearchView into an EditText?

Tags: android

I want to transfer my SearchView function to an EditText. How can I do that? when I tried to transfer it, I got an error or crashing so can you help me with my little problem.

and here is my edittext

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Sorry I'm a newbie in Android.

Comment: If you change Edit text, Use text watcher. Post the error here so that everyone can understand what's your issue

Comment: why u r doing like this
 EditText searchEditText = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)

 what u want actually?

Comment: you can use this library : https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

Comment: sorry the Edittext is for my texthint for the searchview

Comment: Without knowing what errors, it's hard to help

Comment: that code in my searchview is working. so i want to apply that function in my edittext cause i really need a edittext for my project so i wanna convert my searchview into edittext. sorry im newbie in android

Comment: Where's the EditText in the Java code? And what's the error? `findViewById(R.id.editText)` is not here

Comment: thats code is my backup, the files that i converting it is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

**And answer to your question:**

You can not convert searchview into EditText, because searchView is Widget which contains a lot of Views like EditText, Textview.

If you need to manipulate editText of searchview for hint message, color etc you can get EditText from searchview. Actually its called `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
AutoCompleteTextView EditText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
```

**EDIT**

If you want EditText behave like SearchView

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Isn't it `android.R.id`?

Comment: I want to transfer my searchview function in my edittext that is i want to happen

Comment: @cricket_007 I'ts not, because I'm using findViewByID() on searchview element

Comment: Without knowing which R you've imported, the standard behavior would import the app package, and that id isn't defined by default. So, you might need to qualify for the Android SDK id value

Comment: @cricket_007 R is standard app package and I'm actually using code as above inside my project. It's working.

Comment: i have little favor can you apply the above function in my searchview in this code. im very confused how to apply it, So it gonna work like my searchview. thanks for your help

Comment: @madara09 What actually you're trying to do? Are you trying to make searhview not in your toolbar, but inside your layout?

Comment: Yeah. Instead of searchview, i want it ito be edittext

Comment: If you didin't know you can add SearchView element inside your layout. Don't make it comlicated and use it with standard behavior.

Comment: @madara09 Next time you ask a question Please make some effort and make yuor question understandable, bacause ATM we all wasting our precious time to answer question we don't even understand

Comment: Sorry for my English im japanese im not great in english sorry

Comment: Thank for your help im gonna try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't put an EditText inside of the menu xml the way you've written

You can try this instead

```
<menu 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_button_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.EditText"  />
```

If that's not what you mean, and you've instead put the EditText in the Activity, then you're missing a `findViewById` to get it, and it isn't part of the options menu, so you're not going to be replacing the SearchView where it is in the question.

Instead, go to onCreate method, and set the hint and add a `TextWatcher` instead of the Query listener

Comment: yeah, i wanna put my searchivew inside of my activity. so i dont need it in my menu xml

Comment: You mean EditText? Again, you're simply missing findViewById. Try to make a [mcve].

Comment: this is i want. i want to transfer my searchview function in my edittext is that possible?

Comment: I don't know what that means. You have an Action view. And  you say that you want to make it an EditText, so that's what I have shown